# Why are references forbidden in std::variant?

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, variant

I use `boost::variant` a lot and am quite familiar with it. `boost::variant` does not restrict the bounded types in any way, in particular, they may be references:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <cassert>
int main() {
  int x = 3;
  boost::variant<int&, char&> v(x); // v can hold references
  boost::get<int>(v) = 4; // manipulate x through v
  assert(x == 4);
}
```

I have a real use-case for using a variant of references as a view of some other data.

I was then surprised to find, that `std::variant` does not allow references as bounded types, `std::variant<int&, char&>` does not compile and it says [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) explicitly:

*A variant is not permitted to hold references, arrays, or the type void.*

I wonder why this is not allowed, I don't see a technical reason. I know that the implementations of `std::variant` and `boost::variant` are different, so maybe it has to do with that? Or did the authors think it is unsafe?

PS: I cannot really work around the limitation of `std::variant` using `std::reference_wrapper`, because the reference wrapper does not allow assignment from the base type.

```
#include <variant>
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>

int main() {
  using int_ref = std::reference_wrapper<int>;
  int x = 3;
  std::variant<int_ref> v(std::ref(x)); // v can hold references
  static_cast<int&>(std::get<int_ref>(v)) = 4; // manipulate x through v, extra cast needed
  assert(x == 4);
}
```

Comment: A cast or `std::get<int_ref>(v).get()`, to be fair.

Comment: You can use pointers though no?

Comment: Same problems as `optional<T&>`: do you assign through or reseat the reference?

Comment: @Galik In my application I could make it work with pointers, but I would have to write a lot of extra code. I have a lot of `boost::get` calls, which work seamlessly if the variant holds full types or references. It wouldn't work a seamlessly with pointers.

Comment: Sorry, should have said `boost::get` and `boost::apply_visitor` calls. I could simply wrap the first to handle pointers seamlessly, but it is not easy to wrap second.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Fundamentally, the reason that `optional` and `variant` don't allow reference types is that there's disagreement on what assignment (and, to a lesser extent, comparison) should do for such cases. `optional` is easier than `variant` to show in examples, so I'll stick with that:

```
int i = 4, j = 5;
std::optional<int&> o = i;
o = j; // (*)
```

The marked line can be interpreted to either:

1. Rebind `o`, such that `&*o == &j`. As a result of this line, the values of `i` and `j` themselves remain changed.
2. Assign through `o`, such `&*o == &i` is still true but now `i == 5`.
3. Disallow assignment entirely.

Assign-through is the behavior you get by just pushing `=` through to `T`'s `=`, rebind is a more sound implementation and is what you really want (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39985029/2069064), as well as a Matt Calabrese talk on [Reference Types](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hKIYbf1fsLw)).

A different way of explaining the difference between (1) and (2) is how we might implement both externally:

```
// rebind
o.emplace(j);

// assign through
if (o) {
    *o = j;
} else {
    o.emplace(j);
}
```

The [Boost.Optional](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/rebinding_semantics_for_assignment_of_optional_references.html) documentation provides this rationale:

> Rebinding semantics for the assignment of *initialized* optional references has been chosen to provide **consistency among initialization states** even at the expense of lack of consistency with the semantics of bare C++ references. It is true that `optional<U>` strives to behave as much as possible as U does whenever it is initialized; but in the case when `U` is `T&`, doing so would result in inconsistent behavior w.r.t to the lvalue initialization state.
>
> Imagine `optional<T&>` forwarding assignment to the referenced object (thus changing the referenced object value but not rebinding), and consider the following code:
>
> ```
> optional<int&> a = get();
> int x = 1 ;
> int& rx = x ;
> optional<int&> b(rx);
> a = b ;
> ```
>
> What does the assignment do?
>
> If `a` is *uninitialized*, the answer is clear: it binds to `x` (we now have another reference to `x`). But what if a is already *initialized*? it would change the value of the referenced object (whatever that is); which is inconsistent with the other possible case.
>
> If `optional<T&>` would assign just like `T&` does, you would never be able to use Optional's assignment without explicitly handling the previous initialization state unless your code is capable of functioning whether after the assignment, `a` aliases the same object as `b` or not.
>
> That is, you would have to discriminate in order to be consistent.
>
> If in your code rebinding to another object is not an option, then it is very likely that binding for the first time isn't either. In such case, assignment to an *uninitialized* `optional<T&>` shall be prohibited. It is quite possible that in such a scenario it is a precondition that the lvalue must be already initialized. If it isn't, then binding for the first time is OK while rebinding is not which is IMO very unlikely. In such a scenario, you can assign the value itself directly, as in:
>
> ```
> assert(!!opt);
> *opt=value;
> ```

---

Lack of agreement on what that line should do meant it was easier to just disallow references entirely, so that most of the value of `optional` and `variant` can at least make it for C++17 and start being useful. References could always be added later - or so the argument went.

Comment: The explanation makes sense, thank you. As a naive user, though, I expect my variant to behave exactly like the type it currently holds. I cannot rebind references, so I wouldn't expect variant to rebind upon assignment.

Comment: "rebind is a more sound implementation and is what you really want" I guess you mean "you" in the general sense and not me personally, because I don't want it to rebind.

Comment: @olq_plo I agree that the naive expectation is that `optional<T&>` does assign-through. But that is a bad choice for that type. Note that `boost::optional<T&>` [rebinds](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/rebinding_semantics_for_assignment_of_optional_references.html) .

Comment: Host Jason Turner and Guest Jonathan Müller discuss this issue a bit starting at around 18:54 in [episode 136 of CppCast](https://cppcast.com/2018/02/jonathan-muller/).

Comment: It is a reasonable choice for variant, though, so I perhaps optional and variant shouldn't be forced to act alike.

Comment: @olq_plo I disagree both that (a) it's a reasonable choice for variant and (b) that optional and variant are meaningfully different. If `optional<T>` had different semantics from `variant<nullopt, T>`, that would be very confusing

Comment: If the naive expectation is that optional<T&> does assign-through, then having it rebind is accident prone, which you cant have. Since operations on wrapper types should affect the wrapper, not the thing being wrapped, you cant have it assign-through. That leaves disallowing assignment and forcing us to explicitly assigning-through with `*o=j`

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental reason is that ***a reference must be assigned to something***.
Unions naturally do not - can not, even - set all their fields simultaneously and therefore simply cannot contain references, from the C++ standard:

> If a union contains a non-static data member of reference type the
> program is ill-formed.

`std::variant` is a union with extra data denoting the type currently assigned to the union, so the above statement implicitly holds true for `std:variant` as well. Even if it were to be implemented as a straight class rather than a union, we'd be back to square one and have an uninitialised reference when a different field was in use.

Of course we can get around this by faking references using pointers, but this is what `std::reference_wrapper` takes care of.